# iText7 : com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: Document was closed. It is impossible to execute action

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

I got `com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: Document was closed. It is impossible to execute action.` error on iText7.

```
1   // UPDATE FROM HERE             
2   PdfFont font;               
3   {               
4       GcsFilename gcsFilename = new GcsFilename("fonts", "msgothic001.ttf");          
5       try (GcsInputChannel inputChannel =         
6           gcsService.openPrefetchingReadChannel(gcsFilename, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) {       
7           font =      
8               PdfFontFactory.createFont(  
9                   getBytes(Channels.newInputStream(inputChannel)),
10                  PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H,
11                  true);
12      }           
13  }               
14  // UPDATE UNTIL HERE                
15                  
16  WriterProperties wp = new WriterProperties();               
17  wp.useSmartMode();              
18  try (PdfDocument writeDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(outputStream, wp))) {             
19                  
20      List<Integer> keyList = Arrays.asList(Integer.valueOf(1), Integer.valueOf(2), Integer.valueOf(3));          
21      for (Integer keyNumber : keyList) {         
22          LOGGER.info(keyNumber);                                                   // (1)        
23          ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();       
24          try (PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(baos);        
25              PdfDocument readDoc =   
26                  new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(inputBytes)), writer)) {
27              PdfAcroForm pdfAcroForm = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(readDoc, false);  
28              Map<String, PdfFormField> fieldMap = pdfAcroForm.getFormFields();   
29              if (fieldMap != null && fieldMap.size() > 0) {      
30                  Set<String> fieldNameSet = new HashSet<>(fieldMap.keySet()); 
31                  for (String fieldName : fieldNameSet) {
32                      pdfAcroForm.renameField(fieldName, fieldName + "_" + keyNumber);
33                  }
34                  fieldMap = pdfAcroForm.getFormFields();
35              }   
36                  
37                  
38              // UPDATE FROM HERE 
39              PdfFormField form = fieldMap.get("Customer_" + keyNumber);              
40              form.setFont(font).setValue("Test Test");   
41              // UPDATE UNTIL HERE    
42                  
43          }                                           // (2) We got the error on this line        
44                  
45          try (PdfDocument readDoc =      
46              new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray())))) { 
47              readDoc.copyPagesTo(1, readDoc.getNumberOfPages(), writeDoc, new PdfPageFormCopier());  
48          }       
49      }           
50  }
```

I got this output.

```
13:55:45.962 1      // (1)
13:55:47.252 2      // (1)
13:55:47.782 com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: Document was closed. It is impossible to execute action.
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.checkClosingStatus(PdfDocument.java:1887)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.getWriter(PdfDocument.java:645)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfObject.makeIndirect(PdfObject.java:228)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDictionary.makeIndirect(PdfDictionary.java:491)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDictionary.makeIndirect(PdfDictionary.java:57)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfObject.makeIndirect(PdfObject.java:249)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDictionary.makeIndirect(PdfDictionary.java:479)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDictionary.makeIndirect(PdfDictionary.java:57)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFont.makeObjectIndirect(PdfFont.java:600)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfType0Font.getFontDescriptor(PdfType0Font.java:672)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfType0Font.flushFontData(PdfType0Font.java:828)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfType0Font.flush(PdfType0Font.java:600)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.flushFonts(PdfDocument.java:1848)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.close(PdfDocument.java:800)
    at (our source (2) )
```

Why I got this error? How can I fix?

**[UPDATE]**
I found setting value with font "MS Gothic" (Standard font on Japanese Windows) cause this error. It seems some fonts cause this error while others not. I also tried with HELVETICA, but it does not cause error. I have updated my program (from line 1 to 14, and line 38 to 41).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made an almost literal copy of your code:

```
package com.itextpdf.samples;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import com.itextpdf.forms.PdfAcroForm;
import com.itextpdf.forms.PdfPageFormCopier;
import com.itextpdf.forms.fields.PdfFormField;
import com.itextpdf.io.font.FontProgram;
import com.itextpdf.io.font.FontProgramFactory;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.WriterProperties;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FontProgram fontProgram = FontProgramFactory.createFont("c:/windows/fonts/msgothic.ttc,1");

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("test.pdf");
        WriterProperties wp = new WriterProperties();
        wp.useSmartMode();
        try (PdfDocument writeDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(outputStream, wp))) {

            for (int keyNumber = 0; keyNumber < 3; keyNumber++) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                try (PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(baos);
                    PdfDocument readDoc =
                        new PdfDocument(new PdfReader("form.pdf"), writer)) {
                    PdfAcroForm pdfAcroForm = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(readDoc, false);
                    Map<String, PdfFormField> fieldMap = pdfAcroForm.getFormFields();
                    if (fieldMap != null && fieldMap.size() > 0) {    
                        Set<String> fieldNameSet = new HashSet<>(fieldMap.keySet()); 
                        for (String fieldName : fieldNameSet) {
                            pdfAcroForm.renameField(fieldName, fieldName + "_" + keyNumber);
                        }
                        fieldMap = pdfAcroForm.getFormFields();
                    }

                    PdfFormField form = fieldMap.get("name_" + keyNumber);              
                    form.setFont(PdfFontFactory.createFont(fontProgram)).setValue("Test Test");
                }


                try (PdfDocument readDoc =
                    new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray())))) {
                    readDoc.copyPagesTo(1, readDoc.getNumberOfPages(), writeDoc, new PdfPageFormCopier());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't throw any errors when I run it.

I had to make some changes, because I didn't know what parameters such as `keyList` were about. Can you execute my example, and tell me if the problem persists?

- If my example still throws an error: maybe you aren't using the most recent version of iText 7. Please upgrade and try anew.
- If my example doesn't throw an error: try adapting my example step by step until the error happens again. Tell us which was the last step you performed before the error occurred.

**Update:**

When you create a `PdfFont` and when you use that `PdfFont` instance in the context of a `PdfDocument`, that `PdfFont` "belongs" to that document, and you can no longer reuse it. You should create a new `PdfFont` instance for every document. This doesn't mean you can't reuse a `FontProgram` though.

I'll have updated my example. I use the `FontProgramFactory` to create a `FontProgram` (I used the quick & dirty way). I don't reuse any `PdfFont`, but I use the `FontProgram` to create a new `PdfFont` for every `PdfDocument`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I found setting form value with font "MS Gothic" (standard font on Japanese Windows) cause this error. It looks some fonts cause this error while others not. I also tried with HELVETICA, it does not cause error. I have updated my program.

Comment: I'll update my answer. The short answer: it is not allowed to reuse a `PdfFont` object. You should reuse a `FontProgram` instead.

Comment: I have updated the example in my answer. I was able to reproduce the error when using msgothic.ttc, then I fixed the error by reusing a `FontProgram` instead of a `PdfFont`.